# lambda calculus: passing two values to a single parameter without currying

Tags: currying, lambda-calculus

I cannot understand why the following beta reduction is permitted in untyped lambda calculus:

```
(λx.x y) (u v) -> ((u v) y)
```

Specifically I cannot understand how one can pass two parameters `u` and `v` to a single parameter `x` in the `λx.x` part.
To permit the above shouldn't I use currying and have two parameters? Like this—

```
(λx.(λy.(x y))) (u v)
```

Answer (score 12):

> specifically I cannot understand how one can pass two parameters u and v

You're not passing two parameters `u` and `v`. You're passing `(u v)`, which is a single value, or term: the value of `u` applied to `v`.

Compare this with ordinary arithmetic: you can apply a function such as `sin` to a compound term like `sin(x + 1)` because `x+1` denotes a single value, even though it is the application of the function `+` to two arguments `x` and `1`.